# Dynamic IAM Policies for AWS TransferFamily with Custom Identity Provider - Lambda

Tags: lambda, identity-management, aws-transfer-family

I was trying to setup Custom Identity Provider (lambda) for the AWS transfer family. I was able to setup successfully with both Username/Password and SSH authentication. But while trying I was using two different roles with policies attached giving permission only for the users specific folders. I am wondering is there a way where I can dynamically create the policies based of the users and their HomeDirectory, instead of roles for each users.

Eg: For the Server managed users we do have policy like below, the same policy can be attached to all the users and it evaluates dynamically.

````
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeBucket}"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${transfer:HomeFolder}/*",
                        "${transfer:HomeFolder}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "HomeDirObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectACL",
                "s3:PutObjectACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:HomeDirectory}*"
        }
    ]
}     ```


Is there an way to achieve the same as above for the custom Identity provider with lambda and Secrets manager?
````

Answer (score 0):

Replace HomeDirectory to Username

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:UserName}"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${transfer:UserName}/*",
                        "${transfer:UserName}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "HomeDirObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectACL",
                "s3:PutObjectACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${transfer:UserName}*"
        }
    ]
}
```